# Google Plus not reading from meta tags

Tags: meta-tags, google-plus, google-plus-one, schema.org

Below are the meta tags I am using for Google plus

```
    <html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Watch Movies Online">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Watch Movies"/>
    <meta itemprop="description" content="Watch Movies Online">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="https://www22.verizon.com/images/biglogo.gif" />
```

I see them in view source of the page. when I actually click G+ button, it is not reading the values from here. Not able to figure out what I am missing.. Pls suggest me...

Answer (score 3):

The itemtype that you've specified does not appear to be a valid one. Please note that you can only use types specified by [schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html). Please change the type to a valid one and try again.

Apart from that, it would be good if you can specify the URL of your site where it's not working. Furthermore, you can use the [Google Rich Snippets testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) to test your site. This might help tracking down the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following snippet at the top of the document or add to your  definition:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/**yourschematypegoeshere**">
```

Where you replace "yourschematypegoeshere" with one of these, http://schema.org/docs/full.html.